# google bigquery personalized alerts based on a table column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table in google bigquery in which I calculate a column (think of it as anomaly detection column),
is there a way, within GCP, to send a rule based alert (e.g. once the value in the column is 1)
if not how would you recommend dealing with this issue.
Thanks

Comment: What is calculate the column? I think a request isn't it? And what is running this request? Can you describe your data integration pipeline to help you to plug this alerting at the correct position.

Comment: basically i create a table which calculate the delta of a certain value from last week to this week. the column is the percent of change. i want to be able to get notified that I have, for example, a row (each row belong to entity) that has less than 0.8 from last wee.
i can easily transfer it to a Boolean column of 0/1 if needed

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to use eventarc triggers: when data is inserted into your table, the job is written into cloud audit logs and you can trigger a Cloud Run like this.

With this Cloud Run it's possible to inspect the column you mention and send notifications accordingly.

[Here](https://lakshmanok.medium.com/how-to-trigger-cloud-run-actions-on-bigquery-events-e818ee910560) is a good reference on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Because you run a request to calculate the line and the alert to send, the solution is to get the result of this request and to use it.

You can export data to a file (csv for example) and then to trigger a cloud functions on the file creation on Cloud Storage. The cloud functions will read the file and for each line trigger an alert, or send only one alert with the summary of the file, or to send the file in attachement.

You can also fetch all the line of the request result and publish a PubSub message for each line. Like that, you can process in parallel all the messages with Cloud Function or Cloud Run (this time it's not possible to have only 1 alert with a summary of all the lines, the message are unitary)